# RDP connections keep dropping

Tags: internet, remote-desktop, connection

I have an odd problem on my notebook (HP Pavilion dv7).  My Internet connection seems OK for the most part.  But lately I've been having trouble with Remote Desktop connections.  While I can connect to remote computers, the connection is very flaky, and usually drops after a few seconds.  Sometimes it'll successfully reconnect automatically, and sometimes not.  But even after successful reconnection, it'll just drop again after a few seconds.

This appears to be independent of which RDP host I'm connecting to, and which network I'm connected to locally, whether wireless or wired.

Other remote control apps like TeamViewer and Ammyy seem to work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try a continuous ping to like   *ping 8.8.8.8 -t*  and see how many packets are dropped or time outs you get.

Comment: @Shaul @DaveRook also adding some load to continuous ping might be a good idea. `ping -l 1000 8.8.8.8 -t`
Also open wireshark, filter RDP protocol and check if you receive some RST or FIN packets

Comment: @DaveRook - just started a ping as described to the remote host, during that time I set up a RDP connection, which dropped after about 5 sec.  All this time, not one ping packet lost.

Comment: @mnmnc - ping - see comment above

Comment: @Shaul Start Wireshark and monitor the packets that travel to you. I'm pretty sure you will see RST or FIN. Also check this article for possible configuration changes in regards to connection timeout and keep-alive: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx

Comment: @mnmnc - this is pretty weird.  I downloaded and ran wireshark, and now suddenly the RDP connections are stable!  Is that not just extremely strange?

Comment: @Shaul Yeap. a bit strange. do you got any malware protection? av? try scanning your pc with different av software..

Comment: @mnmnc - Just ran a full ESET scan.  0 threats found...

Comment: @Shaul Check the MTU on your network card and MTU on switch router - maybe there is a difference and some packets are dropped. Try adjusting the quality of RDP connection in the settings. Check if only RDP is affected - possibly watching Youtube videos have the same problem with crashing video buffer?

Comment: @mnmnc - oho, that's interesting now that you mention about YouTube.  I have noticed that sometimes YouTube streaming acts a little weird - like resetting the video back to the beginning, or not loading in the first place.  Pardon my ignorance, but what's the connection between YouTube and RDP?  What is MTU, and how do I make the adjustments you mentioned?

Comment: MTU is maximum transmission unit - it is how much data your network cad think it can place inside the network packet/datagram. If your network card has a setting to put 1500 KBytes in the packet and your router accept only 1492 you will sometimes see packets dropped by router because it will not accept packets when you send the biggest possible for you. Check it here: http://superuser.com/questions/37686/how-to-tell-what-mtu-is-being-used-in-windows-xp   How to check it on your router you must check with its manual - depends on the router.

Comment: either way .. if it is not only RDP that is failing you have more things to check - like loose cable, worn-out plug, interference. Check if the same happens when you are connected wirelessly and with wire - if so - the problem is with your network card or router. If no then the problem will be with cabling or device driver on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

This sound like an administrative problem the fact that VNC protocol seems the to be working (teamviewer and ammyy are VNC clients) fine. Which would indicate that it is either a User are RDP setting on the server. If your company use's an Active Directory get them to check the session limit under the sessions tab(If it's windows of course), also if this is happening to more that one user it, get the administrator to check the RDP Session Host Configuration for the override setting.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer.  Please note that this problem is independent of the RDP host.  Also please read comments on the question, indicating that since installing & running Wireshark, the problem seems to have stopped for the time being.

Comment: Teamviewer is a VNC client? Could you please provide a source to substantiate this claim?